# Excel If formula

Tags: sql, excel, if-statement, worksheet-function, worksheet

I have two sheets. On sheet 1, column D contains category text values (ie. Events, collateral, etc.) and column I contains dollar values. On Sheet 2, each row is labelled after one of those categories, and the columns are labelled by month.

I would like the cell on Sheet 2 to calculate the following pseudocode:

```
IF(Sheet1!D20="Events", then add Sheet1!I20 to R9, if not then add 0)
*Where Sheet1!D20:D40 are all categories for December 
*Where Sheet1!I20:I40 are individual costs for December
*where Sheet2!R are total costs for December
```

Yes this is a budget and yes I'm trying to have one sheet show me items we bought divided by month and the other sheet shows me the totals we spent by month in each category.

I hope this is enough info for someone to help me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making a few assumptions about what you want here, but it seems to me that in Sheet2 you will have the categories listed somewhere - perhaps in Col A. So A9 might contain "Events", R1 probably contains "December" and you want R9 to contain the sum of all values in Col I of Sheet1 from rows where Col D contains "Events".

In R9 I would suggest the formula `=SUMIF(Sheet1!D:D,A9,I:I)`. That could be copied up and down Col R to replicate that for other categories.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming a couple of things here:

Sheet 1 contains rows that look like this:

> Month | Category | Dollars Expense

Let's call those A | B | C for now, even though I know you use D and I.

You want Sheet 2 to look like this:

> Row 1: [Category header] | January | February | March | ...
>
> Row 2: Events | [$ spent in January] | [$ spent in Feb] | ...

If that's true, then SUMIFS() will work for you. In our example, we'd use this to return the sum of January Events expenses (Sheet2!B2 in the example):

> =SUMIFS(Sheet1!$C:$C,Sheet1!$A:$A,Sheet2!$A2,Sheet1!$B:$B,Sheet2!B$1)

This will sum matches to the column header (month) to the months in sheet 1 and the row lead (category) to 1's the categories column.